# Google Play Android Developer API error handling

Tags: android, error-handling, in-app-purchase, verify, google-play-developer-api

I am using APIs https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/purchases/products (Purchases.products) to verify in app purchases. My problem is i can't find documentation on error handling. How can i tell if it is invalid payment from rooted device that uses Lucky Patcher probably meaning purchase with wrong token? The only response i am able to get is - 400 invalid value which i believe, can mean anything.